# How to establish a connection to MySQL in vb 6.0

Tags: vb6

i want to establish a connection to my site database which using MySQL how to do it ?
i'm using visual basic 6.0 
or simply read a text file from server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to MySQL database from Visual Basic 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227706/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-from-visual-basic-6)

Comment: Are you looking to connect to the database for reading/writing?  Or read a text file from the server (file location isn't really important, of course).  That's two very different things and code.

Comment: Use [ADO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic). You can find the proper connection string here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-oledb-mysqlprov/. The link that C-Pound Guru gives has some examples.